# Arrow Function Does Not Return HTML Option Tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrow-functions

I wrote an arrow function in javascript that checks for a specific itemId and then outputs the corresponding HTML option tag. However, for some reason none of the conditional statements execute even though an else statement is set to act as a default return statement.

```
const handleDTime = (e) => {                               //this should be fine
  delivery_time = e.target.value;
};

 <div className="select">
   <select onChange={handleDTime} selected={delivery_time} value={delivery_time}>
                                                                
       {() =>  {                                           //javascript arrow function`
         if (itemId === "60e3a111557dc20017253d84") {
           return (
             <option> July 28, 2021 </option>              //html tag <option>`
             <option> July 29, 2021 </option>  

         );
         } else if (itemId === "60e3a121557dc20017253d87") {
           return (
             <option> July 29, 2021 </option>
             <option> July 30, 2021 </option>  
         );
         }
         else {
           <option> July 30, 2021 </option>
           <option> July 31, 2021 </option>  
         } 
       }}
         
   </select>
 </div>
```

Writing the same function above without the arrow function works fine:

```
<div className="select">
    <select onChange={handleDTime} selected={delivery_time} value={delivery_time}>
       <option> Saturday, July 31 </option>                      //works fine
       <option> Sunday, August 1 </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How can I add conditional statements to the function above to display a certain HTML option tag?

Comment: You don't appear to have a loop anywhere in the code there? I don't understand it, unless you're planning to have a `<select>` with only exactly one `<option>`, which seems to defeat the purpose

Comment: Why would you even need an arrow function inside React jsx ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance meant to say conditional statements. Each <select> takes in an itemID and based on the itemID I'd like to display the corresponding <option> tag.

Comment: @Goran.it Each <select> takes in an itemID and based on the itemID I'd like to display the corresponding <option> tag. The <select> is part of a dropdown. What other way can I use conditional statements to display certain <option> on the dropdown?

Comment: Simple conditional tags like: `{someVariable ? <Comp1 /> : <Comp2 />}` or use the babel jsx control statement, more here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the function, but also never call it.

```
    <select onChange={handleDTime} selected={delivery_time} value={delivery_time}>
                                                            
        {(() =>  {                                           //javascript arrow function
          if (itemId === "60e3a111557dc20017253d84") {
            return (
              <option> July 28, 2021 </option>              //html tag <option>
          );
          } else if (itemId === "60e3a121557dc20017253d87") {
            return (
              <option> July 29, 2021 </option>
          );
          }
          else {
            <option> July 30, 2021 </option>
          } 
        })()}
     
    </select>
```

Note the brackets around the function, and another couple to call it.

UPDATE: if you want to return more than one element, you must wrap the nodes within a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
          ...
          if (itemId === "60e3a111557dc20017253d84") {
            return (
              <>
                <option> July 28, 2021 </option>              //html tag <option>
                <option> July 29, 2021 </option>
              </>
          );
          ...
```

Comment: If we have more than one option for each conditional statement, it seems like we need to create an array? I am getting the error "JSX Expressions must have one parent element".